# Alternative for this cursor

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

```
  Id       groupId     LangId     Title         Category
------    --------- ---------  -------------  -----------
4230        4230        1       aaamrmtwna     srhrtiewuv
14230       4230        2       uphliibxil     ppanvtqwht
24230       4230        3       neutnlvgkt     xbhwwyjqnm
6023        6023        1       aacnjohrjk     ehmjptsgxd
16023       6023        2       mejrzfhgjv     lhieeslqgf
26023       6023        3       pibswsvfxh     pzzhgjtbyt
3338        3338        1       aaeidhaivc     pxbolmwjan
13338       3338        2       lsbeyvtrch     pdtyrcwkdd
23338       3338        3       huewmezblx     kpjzpfryki
5573        5573        1       aafqhvgltp     xzwmguqfro
15573       5573        2       clzywmldud     hdylrqtcka
25573       5573        3       rwkdahwpdq     syhysvkftx
9896        9896        1       aaiaxqdwho     mxdgtdaeqx
19896       9896        2       onufsjeaal     cjrsotvbqt
29896       9896        3       fowufxxujk     xztkjbctru
9040        9040        1       aajjamlqkf     wattqxerjh
19040       9040        2       nrkdzgourq     rmckjjpvfu
29040       9040        3       winkynkdkf     zhfmkqsyvc
5518        5518        1       aamdwlwwgl     kdzsxuzfdp
15518       5518        2       byzzhqqfsr     cdmxmcxyof
25518       5518        3       ylkffbmief     qildnvyqhi
5043        5043        1       aamqnboinl     awtmdhbiuq
15043       5043        2       nachemovnv     rdzlbxqkdv
25043       5043        3       twxyozpzra     hskmwnsbjc
501         501         1       aansttgfjk     bmirdqmpgb
```

I wrote a cursor to get this output (I've inserted that random strings data for test).But if there is more than 1k rows in the table cursors performance getting so slow.I need to write the query alternate this cursor.

This is my cursor :

```
 DECLARE @Id int
 DECLARE @groupId int
 DECLARE @LangId int
 DECLARE @Title nvarchar(50)
 DECLARE @Category nvarchar(50) 
 DECLARE @i int
 DECLARE @Result TABLE
 (
 Id int,
 groupId int,
 LangId int,
 Title nvarchar(50),
 Category nvarchar(50) 
 )
 DECLARE csr_group CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR

 SELECT TOP 100 * FROM SortThis order by LangID, Title

 OPEN csr_group

 FETCH NEXT FROM csr_group INTO @Id , @groupId , @LangId , @Title , @Category 
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0         
    BEGIN 
    set @i = (select Id from @Result where Id = @Id)
        if @i is null
        begin
            INSERT INTO @Result
               (
                [ID]
               ,[GroupId]
               ,[LangId]
               ,[Title]
               ,[Category]
               )
               Select * from SortThis where GroupId = @groupId 
        FETCH NEXT FROM csr_group INTO @Id , @groupId , @LangId , @Title , @Category 
        end
    END 
CLOSE csr_group
DEALLOCATE csr_group

select * from @Result 
order by (Select 0)
OFFSET ((1 - 1) * 25) ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;
```

When I sort the table for Title or Category , every languages of that product should seen in subbuttom and ordered by langId.(like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8klWB.png )

I haven't found an example similar to my problem.Please help.

Comment: What happens when you run over 10000 records? Do you allow duplicate ids?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you could turn into a consumable dataset so we can help you with the code. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start. Also, your final select has an order by but you have no way to know what order they will actually return. You really should use something in the dataset for ordering. I am intrigued by the interesting calculation for offset. That look very weird to me.

Comment: @KevinCook after 1000 records query gettin slower just it.It is not dublicating ids.

Comment: @SeanLange When I order by any column the order that I get was changing and for paging I had to give offset an order so I did that. That is probably a wrong way of use of course.Thats why I'm searching the right query.And the calculation for offset is (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize. I'll very appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: So when you finally reach a groupid of 14230 and it generates a first record of 14230 (since you aren't adding anything to the first record in the id series) you don't see how this code will generate duplicate ids in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer if anyone interests.

```
SELECT
Id, GroupId, LangId, Title, Category FROM
SortThis s2 Order BY (

SELECT TOP 1 s1.Category FROM SortThis s1 WHERE s1.LangId=(
SELECT MIN(LangId) FROM SortThis s3 WHERE s1.GroupId=s3.GroupId
) AND s1.GroupId=s2.GroupId
) , LangId

OFFSET (1-1) * 25 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
```